# Capybara and Ajax request on document ready

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

So I have script on page:

```
$(document).ready ->

  $.rails.ajax
    type: 'POST'
    url: url
    data:
      request:
        'some data': data
    success: (response) ->
      do something
```

And I have feature test:

```
 RSpec.describe 'some test', type: :feature, js: true do
  it 'tests' do
    visit '/'
    page.select 'some value', from: 'id'
    click_on('Some button')
    expect(page).to have_content 'some text'
  end
```

Also some config:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

How to make capybara run those script that should run on document ready? It seems that id doesn't run now.

Comment: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara

Comment: Also you want to do the inverse - fire the ajax call immediately and then set a document ready callback from the success/error handler.

Comment: @max Thank you! I am using solution from this article, but nothing changes. It seems that capybara doesn't fire js on document ready, there are not request.

Comment: @max can it be still advised to use this one, as there are tools that do not require it ? Still thoughbots, thinking about this one https://robots.thoughtbot.com/headless-feature-specs-with-chrome

Comment: What error exactly are you getting, and what is the Ajax request doing on success

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Ajax make request, it does some calculations, generate partial and add it to page (via jquery). So no errors, test just failed because page have no content that added by ajax.

Comment: @denys281 So since the test fails there is an error - add the exact error/failure message to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to tell Capybara to run a script in the page.  If the script is in the page then Chrome will run it (assuming no JS errors, etc).

Since you don't indicate which line the test fails on, or what the exact failure message is, it's tough to tell exactly what the ajax request is loading to the page and whether you're expecting that code to run on the page returned by `visit '/'` or on the page directed to by clicking on the button.  If the former then you need to have an expectation for whatever visible change to the page happens when the ajax request succeeds.  If the latter then most likely you just have `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set too low for the hardware you're testing on (increase it to 5 or 10).